# How to avoid memory problem with kivy graphics?

Tags: python, animation, memory, graphics, kivy

I experience severe problems with the memory. Whenever the amount of drawn objects reaches around 50, the screen freezes and the game ends.(see error message below)

I am using windows, python 3, kivy and geany

All the drawn objects are added to a list, to many elements (around 50) cause performance problems. 
I have already tried to clean the memory by using garbage collect ( import gc, gc.collect() ), but this decreased the speed of the game drasticly even more.

You can find my code and further informations about the game and the problem on Github:
https://github.com/MartinPhilipp/Kivy-towers

```
# adding to the list:

  with self.canvas:
                b = random.choice(("rect", "rect", "rect", "circle", "ornament"))
                red,green,blue = random.random(), random.random(), random.random()
                Color(red,green,blue,1)
                if b == "rect":
                    x = random.randint(build_x-20, build_x+20)
                    size_x = random.randint(50,150)
                    size_y = random.randint(50,100)
                    Rectangle(pos=(x,y),size=(size_x,size_y))
                    p_list.append((b, x, y, red, green, blue, size_x, size_y))

# deleting from the list 

 def destroy(self, playernumber):
        for number, li  in enumerate((self.player1_list, self.player2_list)):
            if number != playernumber:
                continue
            items = len(li)
            if items > 0:
                for i in range(max(items//5,1)):
                    if len(Particle.zoo.keys()) < 10:
                        for x in range(3):
                            Particle(x=li[i][1],y=li[i][2],playernumber=playernumber)
                    del li[i]
            self.renew_screen()
```

This is the error message:

```
MemoryError
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.graphics.instructions.VertexInstruction.radd'
MemoryError
MemoryError
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.graphics.instructions.Instruction.radd'
MemoryError
MemoryError
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.graphics.instructions.VertexInstruction.radd'
MemoryError
SystemError: Unable to realloc memory for free list
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.graphics.buffer.Buffer.grow'
SystemError: Unable to realloc memory for free list
SystemError: Unable to realloc memory for buffer
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.graphics.buffer.Buffer.grow'
SystemError: Unable to realloc memory for buffer
```

Comment: I think that you are constantly adding instructions to the `Canvas` without ever removing any. Every call to `Line`, `Rectangle`, `Color`, etc, adds instructions to the Canvas. I don't see anything that clears the `Canvas` or removes instructions.

Comment: @JohnAnderson is correct, you don't have 50 canvas instructions, it's orders of magnitude more than that.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added "self.canvas.clear()" to the renew_screen function and now the program is running without any problems.